# Is there any caching mechanism in Slick?

Tags: scala, caching, playframework-2.0, slick

I'm new in Slick and Play and I can't find any references about caching in docs(2 and 3rc). Is there any native way in Slick for cache organization or if not tell me, please, why and whats the reasons for not having it? Summary, I hope that somebody help me in this question or show another better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Slick has got anything, it is just for interacting with a RDBMS. But since you are using play framework you have the play cache API:s that you can use, for example in a DAO that wraps Slick. You can read more about it in the play framework docs here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaCache

Answer (score 2):

Also see http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/orm-to-slick.html#read-caching  and the following section